How to use Chrome DevTools (or React Native DevTools) with Github Codespaces?
I am developping my React Native app using Expo with the Github Codespaces IDE. I successfully runned my app on my android phone (using expo start --dev-client --tunnel) and I have the console.log() from my app that appears in my codespace terminal.
However, it is written in the terminal that  JavaScript logs will be removed from Metro in React Native 0.77! Please use React Native DevTools as your default tool. Tip: Type j in the terminal to open (requires Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge)
But when I press j I have the following error:
Debug: Launching DevTools...
Debug: Error launching DevTools: The EDGE_PATH environment variable must be set to a Edge/Chromium executable no older than Edge stable.
Debug: Failed to open the React Native DevTools, see debug logs for more info.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make either Chrome DevTool or even better React Native DevTools (even if I have not completely understood if RNDT is an app by itself, a browser extension, or something else: https://reactnative.dev/docs/react-native-devtools) with Github Codespaces?
Note that I am able to use Codespaces either directly in the browser or with a local VS Code connected to CS. But that I do not have admin right on my Windows machine.
Thank you in advance for any help you could provide.
